# Visual Studio 2010 messes up visually

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Not sure what is going on here, if it's just my computer, or a VS bug. It is annoying.

When scrolling, text in VS sometimes gets really messed up. it also happens to other window elements on occasion.

[image]

I've noticed something similar in Dreamweaver CS4 & CS5, so I don't know if it's my computer or something with WPF.
Any way to fix this problem?

Windows 7 Pro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely a general WPF issue, and could be related to your graphics drivers.

I would recommend looking for updated graphics drivers for your graphics card.  If this doesn't work, try reducing the amount of hardware acceleration, as this tends to clean up many WPF rendering issues.

Comment: NVidia graphics driver update seems to have done the trick. the previous drivers were from september of last year 9-2010. the newest version was from two days ago. If the problem comes back then I'll try turning down my acceleration. The problem of intermittent bugs.

Comment: you replied first, so answer goes to you... never sure of the proper way to chose an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would suspect this is a WPF issue that may be resolved by updating your graphics drivers if your card can handle it as Reed Copsey suggested.

If you don't have any luck with that, you can try turning off some of the hardware-accelerated rendering by going to the *Tools* menu, selecting *Options* then disabling the *Automatically adjust visual experience based on client performance* option and the following two options under the *Environment > General* section.

Answer (score 1):

MSDN put up an article not too long ago that can help troubleshoot the problem.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ff716700

The first two things I would try would be to update your video drivers. Then maybe turn down hardware acceleration.

This KB article touches upon how to do it about half way down the resolution section.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/263039

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problems with my VS2010. It isn't a graphic driver issue but an issue with WPF/VS2010. I was hoping the SP1 would solve this problem, but it didn't.